# Remove YUI Rich Editor Header and make it not collapsible

Tags: html, css, yui

I am using the YUI Rich Editor (`SimpleEditor`) which gives an editor that has a heading that says "Text Editing Tools" and a `+`/`-` button that shows/hides the editing tools. I don't need this, how can I hide them or disable these features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (I) can use a configuration like this:

```
var myConfig = {
    height: '300px',
    width: '522px',
    toolbar: {
        collapse: false,
        titlebar: '',
        draggable: false,
        buttons: [
            { group: 'textstyle', label: 'Font Style',
                buttons: [
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Bold CTRL + SHIFT + B', value: 'bold' },
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Italic CTRL + SHIFT + I', value: 'italic' },
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Underline CTRL + SHIFT + U', value: 'underline' },
                    { type: 'separator' },
                    { type: 'color', label: 'Font Color', value: 'forecolor', disabled: true },
                    { type: 'color', label: 'Background Color', value: 'backcolor', disabled: true }
                ]
            },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { group: 'indentlist', label: 'Lists',
                buttons: [
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Create an Unordered List', value: 'insertunorderedlist' },
                    { type: 'push', label: 'Create an Ordered List', value: 'insertorderedlist' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS to the page:

```
.yui-skin-sam .yui-toolbar-container .yui-toolbar-titlebar {
     display: none;
}
```

For future reference, YUI support is here: http://yuilibrary.com/forum/